# One installer with multiple uninstallers - InnoSetup

Tags: installation, inno-setup, uninstallation

i'm new here, and i will try to be specific:

We have multiple applications and decided to join them into only one installer, with custom wizards etc..

So i copied the source script from the others installers and pasted them inside the main installer, with a lots of changes to the script, and everything is working just fine.

However, i'm into a situation where one of these embedded application needs itself uninstaller..

I mean, i need an uninstaller for the main app, and an uninstaller for this app i've just added in the main app's installer.

Ps.: Having separated installers and calling them during installation is not what i want.

Comment: I don't know why somebody negativated my question, i did a lot of research before asking this, and i couldn't find any answere that points EXACTLY what i want.

Comment: It wasn't me who voted down, but why don't you want to have separate installers. That's the best you can do. And, you can run them silently, if you afraid of their visibility.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know about the /silent and /verysilent mode, however i have a few checkbox that will change the other installer's behavior, i'd need to pass them by parameters, and change the currently separated installer, it would be tough to do it right now, as this envolves quite a lot of files. This is why i'm avoiding this option... I'd rather find a way (if there's any) to create a separated uninstaller (even if its manually).  Plus calling the other installer through [RUN], won't show this installer's progress bar, and the user cant know how long it may take.

Comment: You can write an "uninstaller" (it can be even in Inno Setup `[Code]` section of the "fake installer") that will remove specific files in "current folder" or a folder that is described in a specific registry key (which can be obtained by the "uninstaller" on run). Then you can add it to the registry as an uninstaller for this very app.

Comment: Well, i came to thank you guys for the anweres.

Comment: I ended up calling the separate installer through the [RUN] section, it was tough to modify both installers, but sounds better than doing any other workaround for this.